# How to actually save a file in two place in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do a plugin in wordpress which I want to upload image in two directory. One is for my full image. and another one is thumbnail. So that the full size image does not overload and slow down the whole web page.When user click on that thumbnail then only direct to the full image. I try to search around wordpress codex and found `wp_handle_uploads` but I can't create two callback function that save in two places right?How can I do that?

```
    <?php 
    /*
    Plugin Name: random plug
    Plugin URI: http://example.com/wordpress-plugins/my-plugin
    Description: A plugin demonstrating Cron in WordPress
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Brad Williams
    Author URI: http://wrox.com
    License: GPLv2
    */

//create custom post type
    add_action('init', 'register_tagging_post');

     function register_tagging_post(){
           $tagging_args = array(
               'public' => true,
               'supports' => array(
                   'title',
                   'thumbnail'

               ), 
               'query_var' => 'tagging',
               'rewrite' => array(
                  'slug' => 'tagging',
                  'with_front' => false
               ),
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Albums',
                'singular_name' => 'Album',
                'add_new' => 'Add New Album',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Album',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Album',
                'new_item' => 'New Album',
                'view_item' => 'View Album',
                'search_items' => 'Search Albums',
                'not_found' => 'No Albums Found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Albums Found In Trash'
            ),

           );

           register_post_type('tagging', $tagging_args);


     }

//set enctype to enable file upload
     add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'cpis_image_add_post_enctype');
      function cpis_image_add_post_enctype(){
                echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
        }

     //add metabox
     add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'boj_mbe_create' );

    function boj_mbe_create() {

        //create a custom meta box
        add_meta_box( 'boj-meta', 'My Custom Meta Box', 'boj_mbe_function', 'tagging', 'normal', 'high' );

    }

    function boj_mbe_function( $post ) {

        //retrieve the meta data values if they exist




        ?>

        <input type="file" name="taggr_upload">



        <?php







    }

    //hook to save the meta box data
    add_action( 'save_post', 'boj_mbe_save_meta' );

    function boj_mbe_save_meta( $post_id ) {

        add_filter('upload_dir', 'wallpaper_dir');
            function wallpaper_dir(){
            global $post;
             if ('tagging' == $post->post_type){
               return array(
                'path'    => "C:\\xampp\htdocs\wow\wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yeah/uploads/2013/09", //have to be set
                'url'     => "http://localhost/wow/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yeah/uploads/2013/09", //have to be set
                'subdir'  => "/2013/09", //have to be set
                'basedir' => "C:\\xampp\htdocs\wow\wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yeah/uploads", //have to be set
                'baseurl' => "http://localhost/wow/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/yeah/uploads", //have to be set
                'error'   => false,
            );

            }
            }



     $file = array(
                        'name'     => "yeah" . $_FILES[ 'taggr_upload' ]['name'],
                        'type'     => $_FILES['taggr_upload']['type'],
                        'tmp_name' => $_FILES['taggr_upload']['tmp_name'],
                        'error'    => $_FILES['taggr_upload']['error'],
                        'size'     => $_FILES['taggr_upload']['size']
                    );

                    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );


                wp_handle_upload( $file, $upload_overrides );

            set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );//is this actually how I add thumbnail?

    }

    //create custom post column


    //shortcode


    ?>
```

This is my code, Is this how actually i add thumbnail??

Comment: just use `set_post_thumbnail_size()` or `add image size()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: i dont know where these thumbnail are saved using these function

Comment: They are saved in the same place like the original, but with a small prefix ( of the size ) appended to the filename before extension ( something like filename-300x600.png ) depending on your settings , it would be in uploads or uploads/year/month

Comment: read the doc i linked above..

Comment: @obmerk is that the correct way of adding this function??I have no access to template function.php as I am developing a plugin

Comment: The same function will work for a plugin just the same. used it myself countless times ..

Comment: thanks for ur help bro, so are the usage of set_post_thumbnail_size() in my code are correct? can you please modify it and post it as answer:)

Comment: [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/) is from a core developer, might be handy. I think what you're trying is a bit complicated, research for the functions names at [wordpress.se], there are many techniques laid out over there.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress actually has an option to do this built in, you just need to declare it in your plugin by adding the the right hook.  What I would do is specify a custom thumbnail name and size.  Every time an image is uploaded into the media library, it is then added as not only the full size image, but another copy of the image scaled to the sizes you have specified with the `set_post_thumbnail_size()` function:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: :-) I was 5 seconds slower :-)

Comment: actually the thumbnail I want to show is in my wordpress admin area only and I had register a custom post type as album so a user can upload multiple image for an album. So actually how can I set the thumbnail for all that individual image and save it in my custom directory
??

Comment: i dont know where these thumbnail are saved using these function

Comment: even if you only show the thumbnail on the dashboard, why would you not use the custom thumb size function above?  There's no difference to the availability or sourcing of the file, and there's way more overhead to storing the file elsewhere.

Comment: they're saved to the wp-content/uploads folder.  I HIGHLY recommend you use the built in functionality.  Otherwise, if your users decide to use a different theme, or a different gallery plugin, they won't be able to access the custom thumbnails.

Comment: hey bro, thanks but is this how actually I should add my code??If it is, then why my thumbnail still not exist in neither of my custom file directory nor wp-content/uploads. Sorry for not familiar with that function. You can just view the last few line i have a comment